# Xcode Playground: Trying to disable output for specific lines of code

Tags: xcode, performance, output

I have a very long loop that takes forever in playground because of the constant output. Is there a way to disable output for certain lines of code? I still want the whole thing to run, I just don't want to wait forever to see the result.

FYI - I know I can run the code on demand but that doesn't matter . It still takes forever. I don't mind it running continuously, I just want it to run without all of the output.

FYI - I also know that playground is not used for performance. I just don't want to wait forever to see a result. I'm not testing performance.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073192/swift-playground-execution-speed).

To summarize the portion relevant to your question: wrapping your code in a tuple will prevent it from having output in Xcode Playgrounds and speed up execution time.

For example:

```
input: var x = 10 // output: 10
input: (var x = 10) // output: None
```